# How can I stop this ImportError: cannot import name 'check_role'

Tags: python, flask, python-import

Folder structure:

```
├── app
│   ├── admin
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── home
│   │   ├── forms.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── templates
│       ├── admin
│       │   ├── departments
│       │   ├── members
│       │   └── roles
│       ├── auth
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── errors
│       │    
│       └── home
│           ├── admin_dashboard.html
│           ├── dashboards
│              └── treasurers
├── config.py
├── instance
│   └── config.py
├── migrations
├── requirements.txt
├── run.py
└── tests.py
```

I have checked other questions but none helps me. Here is the import in app/auth/views.py:

```
from ..home.views import check_role
from . import auth
from .forms import LoginForm, MemberRegistrationForm, LeaderRegistrationForm
from .. import db
from ..models import Member
```

**check_role** is a function in app/home/views.py. When I run my app and open the browser I see this error:

```
flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "run", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/eric/Documents/coding/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 235, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/eric/Documents/coding/adminsystem/run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import create_app
  File "/home/eric/Documents/coding/adminsystem/app/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .home.views import check_role
  File "/home/eric/Documents/coding/adminsystem/app/home/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/eric/Documents/coding/adminsystem/app/home/views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ..auth.forms import MemberRegistrationForm
  File "/home/eric/Documents/coding/adminsystem/app/auth/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/home/eric/Documents/coding/adminsystem/app/auth/views.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..home.views import check_role
ImportError: cannot import name 'check_role'
```

What could be the possible cause of this?

Comment: If relative imports drive you insane, try an absolute one.

Comment: Tried that, no changes.

Comment: please post the folder structure and all files in the folders.

Comment: Just trying to help... Could you try 'from app.home.views import check_role'. Please be sure you checked this function name.